# Django and OpenLayers: Not displaying KML data

Tags: django, maps, openlayers, geodjango

I'm a Django/OpenLayers newbie, and I've been following various tutorials, especially [this one](https://code.google.com/p/geodjango-basic-apps/wiki/FOSS4GWorkshop). I use a view that calls a built-in GeoDjango template to render KML dynamically, which I try to pass to a page to render the map using OpenLayers. However, instead of producing a map showing all of the points from my KML file, all I get is the default map, the same as if I never added the 'kml' layer in my map.html file. I suspect that somehow the KML file is not getting loaded into OpenLayers, but I simply don't understand why not, or how I can test whether the KML data loaded successfully. Alternately, the KML is being loaded successfully, but not displaying properly for some reason.

The relevant model from my models.py:

```
class Dialect(models.Model):
    dialectCode = models.CharField("short code for location", max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    dialectNameEn = models.TextField("human readable name of the dialect")
    dialectTag = models.ManyToManyField('DialectTag',blank=True, null=True)
    locationName = models.TextField("human readable location name", blank=True)
    locationNameAr = models.TextField("Arabic name of location if available", blank=True)
    centerLoc = models.PointField("a point representing this dialect", srid=4326)
    regionLoc = models.MultiPolygonField("multipolygon geometry", blank=True,  null=True) #optional regional info
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.dialectCode
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.contrib.gis.shortcuts import render_to_kml
from dialectsDB.models import *

def all_kml(request):
     locations  = Dialect.objects.kml()
     return render_to_kml("gis/kml/placemarks.kml", {'places' : locations})
# Create your views here.

def map_page(request):
     lcount = Dialect.objects.all().count()
     return render_to_response('map.html', {'location_count' : lcount})
```

Simple urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from dialectsDB.views import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'dialects.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^kml/', all_kml),
    url(r'^map/', map_page)
)
```

The map.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
      <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var style = new OpenLayers.Style({
            'externalGraphic': OpenLayers.Util.getImagesLocation() + "marker.png",
            'graphicHeight': 25,
            'graphicWidth': 21,
            'graphicXOffset': -10.5,
            'graphicYOffset': -12.5
        });
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
        var kml = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {strategies: OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), styleMap: style, visibility: true,
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({url: "/kml/", format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML()})});
       map.addLayers([wms,kml]);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      </script>

</body>
```

Also, a snippet of the KML output, which works when loaded directly into Google Maps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>

  <Placemark>
    <name>ArSab</name>
    <description>ArSab</description>
    <Point><coordinates>42.615967,17.140791</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>ArBah</name>
    <description>ArBah</description>
    <Point><coordinates>50.534363,25.985207</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>LvBsh</name>
    <description>LvBsh</description>
    <Point><coordinates>35.757751,34.320755</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
[...]
```

Comment: If there are no errors, this may well be projection related. ie, it is loading, but you aren't seeing anything because your kml is in degrees, while your map is in meters.

Comment: from his code, seems he use default projection EPSG 4326, and from the kml file, the projection there seems to be 4326 as well

Comment: So I really would like some way to check that the Layer is actually receiving and loading the KML data. No matter WHAT the URL I give it is, (/foobar/ which doesn't exist, etc), I get the same result - no error messages, nothing. Is there so way to check whether it is successfully getting the KML data?

Comment: Another test: I put just the map.html page into another folder, along with a file arabicpoints.kml. I change the "protocol:..." line to read "protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({url: "arabicpoints.kml", format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML()})", but still it does not seem to be showing the datapoints from the KML file. I've also tried with an absolute url (file:///D:/...), again with no luck.

Comment: Are you sure that it comes from the KML? I mean, do you even see a map with only the WMS layer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your webpage network traffic by using firebug(in firefox) or developer tool (in chrome)?

As you mentioned above, if it load successfully, then check if you get any error messages from you webpage.

If no error message on the console, then check if there are any layer overlay. sometimes it may be covered by other layers, first load layer usually display on the very bottom of the page.

Comment: The only error I'm getting from the webpage is a CSS error, that I think is being thrown by the imported OpenLayers javascript (or maybe from some firefox extension?):
Style sheet could not be loaded. http://a.fsdn.com/sd/classic.css?release_20140811
That even seems to have disappeared on reload.
I'm not sure how to check for layer overlay. If I add {layers: 'basic'} to the KML layer and only load that, I just get a "TypeError: this.baseLayer is null"

Comment: I am not totally sure what you mean by webpage traffic. I am running this on the local server provided by manage.py's runserver. However, I do notice that the command line shows when a page has been served - presumably if the map.html page was also getting the /kml/ page, the runserver command would output something like:
[DATE TIME] "GET /map/ HTTP/1.1"
[DATE TIME] "GET /kml/ HTTP/1.1"

Since it is not outputting a GET to /kml/, does this mean there's something wrong with the syntax of the URL passed to OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The code I was relying on (not sure exactly from where) was missing on small and apparently vital difference:
The code I was using read:

```
var kml = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {strategies: OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), [...]
```

The correct version is:

```
var kml = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()], [...]
```

Well that was a frustrating afternoon spent trying to diagnose the problem.

Incidentally, as mentioned in one of my comments, when the page is working correctly, the manage.py runserver console shows GETs on both /map/ and /kml/.